# Error HH600: Compilation failed ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';'

Tags: hardhat, chainlink

I was doing the chainlink hackton lesson "DeFi Staking App: Code Along" [link](https://youtu.be/-48_hdo9_gg) when I got this error while running yarn hardhat compile:

ParserError: Expected ',' but got ';'
--> contracts/Staking.sol:59:24:
|
59 |             pastRewards;
|                        ^

Error HH600: Compilation failed

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

error Staking__TransferFailed();
error Stakig__NeedsMoteThanZero();


contract Staking {
    IERC20 public s_stakingToken;
    ERC20 public s_rewardToken;
    // somones address -> how much they staked
    mapping(address => uint256) public s_balances;

   // mapping of how much each address has been paid
   mapping(address => uint256) public s_userRewardPerTokenPaid;

   // a mapping of how much rewards each address has to claim
   mapping(address => uint256) public s_rewards;

uint256 public constant REWARD_RATE =100;
uint256 public s_totalSupply;
uint256 public s_rewardPerTokenStored;
uint256 public s_lastUpdateTime;

modifier updateReward(address account){
    s_rewardPerTokenStored = rewardPerToken();
    s_lasrUpdateTime = block.timestamp;
    s_rewards[account] = earned(account);
    s_userRewardPerTokenPaid[account] = s_rewardPerTokenStored;
    _;
}

modifier moreThanZero(uint256 amount){
    if( amount ==0){
        revert Stakig__NeedsMoteThanZero();
    }
    _;

}
    


constructor(address stakingToken, address rewardToken) {
    s_stakingToken = IER20(stakingToken);
    s_rewardToken = IER20(rewardToken);
}

function earned(address account) public view returns (uint256){
    uint256 currentBlanace = s_balances[account];
    // how much they have paid alredy
    uint256 amountPaid = s_userRewardPerToken[account];
    uint256 currentRewardPerToken = rewardPerToken();
    uint256 pastRewards = s_rewards[account];
    uint256 _earned = ((currentBalance *(currentRewardPerToken - amountPaid)/1e18) + 
        pastRewards;
    return _earned; 

}



function rewardPerToken public view returns(uint256) {
    if (s_totalSupply ==0){
        return s_rewardPerTokenStored;
    }
    return s_rewardPerTokenStored + (((block.timestamp -s_lastUpdateTime) * REWARD_RATE * 1e18/ s_totalSupply);
}

function stake(uint256 amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) moreThanZero(amount) {
    s_balances[msg.sender] = s_balances[msg.sender] + amount;
    s_totalSupply = s_totalSupply + amount;
    // emit event
    bool success = s_stakingToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    // require(success, "Failed");
    if(!success) {
        revert Staking__TransferFailed();
    }

}
```

}

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount) external updateReward(msg.sender) moreThanZero(amount) {
    s_balances[msg.sender] = s_balances[msg.sender] - amount;
    s_totalSupply = s_totalSupply - amount; 
    bool success = s_stakingToken.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    if(!success) {
        revert Staking__TransferFailed();
    }

}

function claimReward() external updateReward(msg.sender) {
    uint256 reward = s_rewards[msg.sender];
    bool succes = s_rewardToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
    if(!success){
        revert Staking__TransferFailed();
    }
    

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
function rewardPerToken public view returns(uint256) {
    if (s_totalSupply ==0){
        return s_rewardPerTokenStored;
    }
    return s_rewardPerTokenStored + (((block.timestamp -s_lastUpdateTime) *     REWARD_RATE * 1e18/ s_totalSupply);
}
```

you forgot the function parenthesis. It should looks like `function rewardPerToken()`

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. Silly mistake.